# How to create a schema in sqlcmd that is scoped to one specific user? Do I need to add explicit deny rules individually?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am looking at docs and can't seem to figure out how to do this with a wildcard or blanket permission without doing individual deny statements

Comment: What do you mean by `schema in sqlcmd`? There is no such thing, schemas are database-level objects that don't depend on client applications. Maybe you can provide an example of what you are after?

Comment: hey @RogerWolf I am speaking about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema?view=sql-server-ver15

I can create the schema, but lets say I have 3 users A,B,C, and I also have three schemas X,Y,Z. I need to scope A to X, B to Y, C to Z. So Users can't access other users schema. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a real-world scenario, when you most probably will need:

- Multiple users needing the same level of access;
- Users being unable to change or drop objects, such as tables, in your database.

here is the approach you can use. You can create a role which will have the necessary permissions on a schema, so whatever objects will be placed into that schema in the future, the role will have access to them:

```sql
create role SchemaUser_X authorization dbo;
go
create schema Schema_X authorization dbo;
go
-- You can add or remove permissions here, as necessary
grant select, update, delete, insert, execute on schema::Schema_X to SchemaUser_X;
go
```

After that, you can add your users as role members:

```sql
create user User_X without login; -- Or by your preferred means
go
alter role SchemaUser_X add member User_X;
go
-- Repeat with as many users as need access to [Schema_X]
```

P.S. If you actually need to allow your users to manage objects within their corresponding schemas, such as creating tables, views, procedures, etc. then you can turn these roles into schema owners:

```sql
create role SchemaUser_X authorization dbo;
go
create schema Schema_X authorization SchemaUser_X;
go
-- Grants are unnecessary as the role has CONTROL permission on schema in this case
```

However, in most cases you wouldn't want that.